# Representing Directed & Weighted Graphs as an Unique Sequence

Tags: python, data-structures, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I'm working with networkx graphs (directed and weighted) and I want to represent these graphs in sequences (list). I have to preserve the weights and directions of the graphs somehow in this sequence. More specifically, I am working with knowledge graphs (KG);
[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOJyA.png). Right now, the graphs are quite simple (2-5 nodes, with each nodes usually having 1 edge, 2 at max). Here is a piece of code that can reproduce the examples above:

```py
import networkx as nx

sample_graphs = [{'directed': True,
  'multigraph': False,
  'graph': {},
  'nodes': [{'type': 'INTERNAL',
    'name_': 'Q211930',
    'id': 0,
    'label': 'Marxism–Leninism'},
   {'type': 'ANSWER_CANDIDATE_ENTITY',
    'name_': 'Q7264',
    'id': 1,
    'label': 'Marxism'},
   {'type': 'QUESTIONS_ENTITY',
    'name_': 'Q1120576',
    'id': 2,
    'label': 'Communist Party of Britain'}],
  'links': [{'name_': 'P279',
    'source': 0,
    'target': 1,
    'label': 'subclass of'},
   {'name_': 'P1142',
    'source': 2,
    'target': 0,
    'label': 'political ideology'}]},
 {'directed': True,
  'multigraph': False,
  'graph': {},
  'nodes': [{'type': 'ANSWER_CANDIDATE_ENTITY',
    'name_': 'Q5968650',
    'id': 0,
    'label': 'labourism'},
   {'type': 'QUESTIONS_ENTITY',
    'name_': 'Q1120576',
    'id': 1,
    'label': 'Communist Party of Britain'}],
  'links': [{'name_': 'P1142',
    'source': 1,
    'target': 0,
    'label': 'political ideology'}]}]

graph_objs = [nx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_graph(graph) for graph in sample_graphs]
```

Is there a way to represent weighted and directed graph as an unique and deterministic sequence while preserving weights and directions? For instance, no matter how many times you run this algorithm for graph `A`, the sequence outputted will always be the same.

I know about the Prufer sequence. However, as far as I know, it's implemented for trees. Thus, Prufer sequence can't preserve the weight and directions of our edges in the graph. Maybe there exist an algorithm that performs a deterministic walk of any graph (leading to 1 path for any given graph). Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not fully clear, would you provide a few examples of graphs, ideally demonstrating the potential differences that the coding should preserve? Can your graphs be cyclic? How many (in/out) edges can be found in a single node?

Comment: I've added some more clarification:) Right now the graphs are quite simple. Most nodes usually have 1 edge and non-cyclic. However future graph datasets might introduce denser cyclic graphs.

Comment: I think the question is still too vague. It would be ideal to provide clear reproducible examples (`networkx` objects as you used this tag) and one or several ideas of how the output could look like. Maybe some minimal code that shows an imperfect result. As of now, this question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers, which is offtopic.

Comment: I can provide a piece of code that reproduce one of the graph. However, I don't have an idea of an example of the output. That's why I'm asking this question:) the output is supposed to be the same and unique for any given graph. Graph A produce sequence A`, B produces B\`, etc... No matter how many times I run this algo on A, I will get A\` (so on and so forth)

Comment: I fully understand that, that's why I'm giving you tips to try to get answers (and not being closed as offtopic/opinion-based) ;)

Comment: Why can't you use the unravelled weight matrix?

Comment: Text is a sequence (of characters). So the JSON representation is a sequence.